# VBA Exception Slipping Through Handler

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, exception

I have inherited a *hideous* Excel VBA application, written by a guy who apparently didn't like functions and comments. Opening the source code is like staring into an abyss of madness, with 9 levels of <strike>hell</strike> indentation awaiting to trap the unwary.

First, the setup.

In the process of debugging an intermittent issue, I have identified a particular line in the primary function as its location. Since the exception is not easy for me to fix, I gave this line, and only this line, an error handler that displays a custom message.

```
    ' Lots of stuff cut out
    On Error GoTo TechReleaseBuildError
    lb_Err1 = BuildDirectories(gj_TechBld.mt_TechRlsOutDir)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Lots of stuff cut out
    Exit Sub
TechReleaseBuildError:
    MsgBox "Error building tech release. Pause the synchronization software and try again."
    Stop
    Resume
End Sub
```

The `Stop` and `Resume` are only there to help debugging, since the normal error messages that pop up don't have an option to debug the error.

Within the `BuildDirectories` function, I have identified one line that was causing the error that was being kicked up to primary function. I have placed error handlers in this function as well.

```
    ' Lots of stuff cut out
    Exit Function
TEST:
    Stop
    Resume

SynchroRetry:
    Dim CurrentError As ErrObject
    CurrentError = Information.err
    SynchroRetryCounter = SynchroRetryCounter + 1
    Debug.Print "Synchro Error, retrying #" + SynchroRetryCounter
    Stop
    If SynchroRetryCounter > 5 Then
        Stop
        Information.err.Raise CurrentError.Number, CurrentError.Source, CurrentError.Description, CurrentError.HelpFile, CurrentError.HelpContext
    Else
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:03 AM#
        Resume
    End If

End Function
```

At the very beginning of `BuildDirectories` I have placed an `On Error GoTo TEST` statement as a catch-all error handler so I can identify what lines they are coming from, and also used the SynchroRetry handler for the one line that I already know causes an issue, which I immediately reset back to the TEST handler. The SynchroRetry handler just waits for 3 seconds and retries, failing after the 5th retry.

```
' For some reason, this line (and only this line so far) causes problems when synchronization software is running.
' The error handler waits for a few seconds then tries again a few times.
Dim SynchroRetryCounter As Integer
SynchroRetryCounter = 0
On Error GoTo SynchroRetry
lj_FSO.CopyFile Source:=lt_RPOFilePath & lt_RPOFileName, Destination:=lt_VinRposDir & "\" & lt_RPOFileName, OverWriteFiles:=True ' Trouble line
On Error GoTo TEST
```

I have verified with Find that these are the only 3 `On Error` statements in the function (the only ones in the module, even). The top-level function also has no `On Errors` other than the two shown.

In brief summary, the top-level function has an error handler on only one line, and the function it encloses also has two error handlers inside it, one for one of its known troublesome lines and a general one that should be encompassing the entire function.

The problem is that some error is occurring that is causing my "Error building tech release." message to display, but does not seem to be triggering the TEST or SynchroRetry error handlers. I cannot imagine how this is possible. I'm relatively new to VBA's monstrosity of an error handling model, but I don't believe I did anything wrong. Did I miss some subtlety here? How is an exception able to bypass my handlers and bubble up the stack like this? I do not believe the assignment or passing of the function value could cause the problem, since their just a Boolean and String value. The problem is also intermittent, and only appears when we have file synchronization software active on the directory this program is copying files to.

Comment: I find each of your code samples very difficult to follow because it forces me to assume the name of the procedure. It would be best if you updated your question to show the names, plus the 'On Error' stuff, and whatever calls are made to other functions/subs.  Also, in VBA, what setting do you have in 'Tools | Options | General Tab for Error handling?

Comment: You mentioned making use of two error handlers in `BuildDirectories`, switching between the two. Is it possible that some `Resume` statement should instead be a `Resume Next`, about where you figure there should be the immediate reset back to the TEST handler?

Comment: Also, that `Information.err.Raise CurrentError.Number,...` bit in the SynchroRetry handler, are you expecting that to be caught by the TEST handler?

Comment: @rskar No, Raising the error there is meant to deliberately throw it up the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a couple hours after I posted this, I managed to figure it out.

The reason that the Debug button wasn't on the error boxes is because in Options the Error Trapping was set to "Break on Unhandled Error". Changing it to "Break in Class Module" brought the button back.

The reason the exceptions were bypassing my error handlers is because they were happening in my SynchroRetry error handler. In particular, I had to change the first few lines from this:

```
Dim CurrentError As ErrObject
CurrentError = Information.err
SynchroRetryCounter = SynchroRetryCounter + 1
Debug.Print "Synchro Error, retrying #" + SynchroRetryCounter
```

to this:

```
Dim CurrentError As New ErrObject
Set CurrentError = Information.err
SynchroRetryCounter = SynchroRetryCounter + 1
Debug.Print "Synchro Error, retrying #" + CStr(SynchroRetryCounter)
```

Note the additions of `New`, `Set`, and `CStr`.

Problem solved.